# How to get the difference between two mysql dumps and update the delta?

Tags: mysql, linux, database-backups

I have exact same mysql database in two different machines. db name is "test". in the database there is a table called "user_records" which has id,name,city . The user table in the first machines database is updating realtime. what i need to do is to compare the user_record table in the first machine with the user_record table in the second machine and restore only the difference to the second machines database table.

there will be newly added rows and updated records in the first database table. need to add those changes in the second database table without "Dropping and recreating the table / replacing the entire table".

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: create trigger on test.user_records table after update and after insert make same operation to another database.user_records.